# Сервисы отправки SMS, не требующие предоставления документов

Tags: service, sms

Здравствуйте, ищу сервисы отправки SMS со своим API, для проверки регистрации на сайте.
[sms.ru](http://sms.ru/) не подойдёт из-за необходимости предоставлять свои документы.

Нужен сервис без подобных ограничений.

**P.S.**
Номера будут в основном из следующих стран: Россия, Белоруссия, Украина.

Comment: логично, что требуют документы. А если завтра спам начнете рассылать?

Comment: Без документов - можно делать через свой мобильный или usb-модем.

Для поиграться и повысить уровень знаний - очень полезно. 

Для серьезных задач само собой заключаются нормальные договора с провайдером услуг.

Comment: smsc.ru Документов не предъявлял, как с абузами не знаю. А точно вам отправка нужна? При регистрации как правило наоборот прием смс нужен, или вообще что-то другое.

Answer (score 0):

mainsms.ru за любое нарушение быстро заблочат, и оператору нажалуются(нужен мобильник для регистрации).